# CW complex vs analytic manifold vs variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, differential-topology

I am looking to gain some intuition into the passage (or obstruction thereof) between different categories of objects one encounters in geometry and topology. To oversimplify things a bit, the preferred object for basic algebraic topology is a CW complex, whereas to a geometer the preferred objects could be smooth or analytic manifolds, or varieties (or even pl structures).

Here is what I know already:

**1.** Given a compact smooth manifold one can find a CW complex which is homotopically equivalent to it (standard Morse theory construction). The converse is not true in general. As trivial obstructions, the CW complex might not be finite, or might not satisfy Poincare duality. So,

*Question 1: Given a finite CW complex, is there any way to determine if there exists a homotopically equivalent smooth manifold? In particular, what are some well-known obstructions?*

**2.** It is well-known that any smooth structure on a manifold, one can find a compatible real analytic structure (Whitney). By a result of Nash (Real algebraic manifolds, Ann. of Math. (2) 56 (1952)), every smooth compact manifold is diffeomorphic to an $n$-dimensional real algebraic subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^{2n + 1}$.

*Question 2: When is a complex manifold diffeomorphic to an affine variety? Again, what could be some obstructions?*

Via Chow's theorem, it is known that a closed complex submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective variety. To use more complicated machinery, Kodaira's embedding theorem says that compact Kahler manifolds with integral Kahler forms are precisely the projective varieties. I am not very conversant with Kahler theory, so

*Question 3: Given a compact complex manifold, how do we know whether it is a Kahler manifold with Hodge metric?*

I anticipate that many answers would be based on negative tests (obstructions). Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably ask these questions separately, since they each have long answers.

Comment: Whitney proved the existence and uniqueness (up to diffeomorphism) of a smooth structure on any $C^k$ manifold for any positive integer $k$. Grauert proved the existence and uniqueness of a real analytic structure under the same hypotheses.

Comment: Compactness is an obvious obstruction to a complex manifold being an affine variety.

Comment: By Hartog's theorem, if we remove the biholomorphic image of a compact set in a single holomorphic chart, from any compact complex manifold, any holomorphic map to affine space extends, so there is still no holomorphic embedding.

Comment: Q1 is a very old question. The input is not a CW complex but rather a Poincare Duality space (CW cpx with some extra structure giving a sort of stable normal bundle). The machine answering this question is what's called surgery theory, and includes the passage from PD-spaces to topological manifolds to PL manifolds to smooth manifolds.

Comment: Practically, for most of the complex manifolds which we know to be projective varieties, the proof of this fact comes from explicit construction of an ample line bundle, not from construction of a Kaehler metric with the Hodge property.

Comment: Up to homotopy equivalence, finite CW complexes are the same as finite simplicial complexes.

Comment: If you allow manifolds to have nonempty boundary, then every finite complex is homotopy equivalent to a compact manifold of some dimension. The manifold can even be taken to be a codimension zero submanifold of n-space (for some large n).